# Web Api 2 API not recognizing Multiple Attributes for Routing (Versioning)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, versioning, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to implement both [Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) and the `VersionedRoute` from [RoutingConstaints Sample](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/RoutingConstraintsSample/ReadMe.txt) but when I use both on a controller, the versioned attribute no longer works.

What would I need to modify on the attribute to get it to play nice with Attribute Routing?

For code example download the sample project (or just look at the few files from the above link) and then modify the routes as such:

```
// When I use the RoutePrefix, VersionedRoute no longer works (Sending "Api-Version" through http header doesn't route correctly
// If I remove the RoutePrefix I can use VersionedRoute again
// What do I need to change in its code to be able to use both?

[VersionedRoute("api/Customers", 1)] // This route would be used as http://url/api/customers with a header of "api-version: 1"
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/Customers")] // This route would be used purely through url versioning of http://url/api/v1/Customers
public class CustomersV1Controller : ApiController {

    /* Other stuff removed */

    [VersionedRoute("api/Customer", 1)] // I'd rather not have to use this here at all and just use a single one on the class, but having both nor just one on either works right now.
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Json(_customers);
    }
}
```

[VersionedRoute Code](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/RoutingConstraintsSample/RoutingConstraints.Server/VersionedRoute.cs)

[VersionConstraint Code](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/RoutingConstraintsSample/RoutingConstraints.Server/VersionConstraint.cs)

Edit: Please let me know if you need more information or even post ideas or things to try :)

Edit2: Here is an example of what I'm trying to do from Troy Hunt's Blog: http://www.troyhunt.com/2014/02/your-api-versioning-is-wrong-which-is.html

Edit3: Here is what I'd like to code to be as close to since it would reduce a lot of the overhead and magic strings.

```
[VersionedRoute("api/Customers", 1)] // This route would be used as http://url/api/customers with a header of "api-version: 1"
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/Customers")] // This route would be used purely through url versioning of http://url/api/v1/Customers
public class CustomersV1Controller : ApiController {

    /* Other stuff removed */
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        // Removed
        return Ok(customers);
    }


    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetById(int id)
    {
        // Removed
        return Ok(customer);
    }
}

[VersionedRoute("api/Customers", 2)] // This route would be used as http://url/api/customers with a header of "api-version: 2"
[RoutePrefix("api/v2/Customers")] // This route would be used purely through url versioning of http://url/api/v2/Customers
public class CustomersV2Controller : ApiController {

    /* Other stuff removed */
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        // Removed
        return Ok(customersThatAreDifferentThanV1);
    }


    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetById(int id)
    {
        // Removed
        return Ok(customerThatIsDifferent);
    }
}
```

Edit: Last bump, trying to only have to write the route version information once per route, at the controller attribute level and not per-action.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @DavidG I'm trying to use both `VersionedRoute("Customer", 1)` which would allow me to use http headers to supply the version #, as well as using a `RoutePrefix("v1/Customer/")` for versioning through the url. Basically I want to support both header and url versioning. However when I apply the `RoutePrefix` the `VersionedRoute` attribute stops working.

Comment: What does your Configuration look like when setting up the project?

Comment: @entropic The full project is linked in the OP: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/RoutingConstraintsSample/RoutingConstraints.Server/App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs

Comment: I don't think you can do exactly what you want using the `VersionedRoute` code you linked AND have `RoutePrefix`. My guess is that the prefix is always applying `api/v1/Customers` to your routes, thereby negating the point of the version HTTP headers.

Comment: @DavidG right I'm wondering how I can modify that code to work with RouteAttributes. The blog I linked mentions getting them to work together but I wasn't able to figure it out and see what I need to change.

Comment: @John The article mentions `Route` but not `RoutePrefix` but there's someone in the comments with what looks like a potential solution.

Comment: At the end of Troy Hunt post is the link to http://webstackoflove.com/asp-net-web-api-versioning-with-media-types/ which includes detail info about versioning your api with media types and attribute routing.

Comment: @DavidG do you know which comment you were talking about? There was another person who asked regarding having issues with RoutePrefix as well but Tony said it was working fine for him :(. Did you mean the guy that added the constant or another comment? Thanks :)

Comment: @MatijaGrcic I'm trying that out now as well, but does it work for doing version specific routes as well or only for the headers? I want to support both header as well as url versioned routes (with the non-versioned url requiring headers or always the oldest version)

Answer (score 13):

The `Route` and `VersionedRoute` attributes are working fine together, but your `RoutePrefix` attribute is also applied to your `VersionedRoute` (try accessing /api/v1/Customers/api/Customer - you'll get a response when the api-version header is set)

The following code would produce the desired behaviour with regards to the two URLs in your example returning the correct responses, but obviously this does not solve your problem of wanting one `VersionedRoute` and one `RoutePrefix` at the top of the class. Another approach would be needed for this. You can, however, have separate controllers for different api versions.

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class CustomersV1Controller : ApiController
{
    /* Other stuff removed */

    [VersionedRoute("Customers", 1)]
    [Route("v1/Customers")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Json(_customers);
    }
}
```

An improvement would be to create your own attribute instead of `Route` so you wouldn't need to prefix the version every time:

```
public class CustomVersionedRoute : Attribute, IHttpRouteInfoProvider
{
    private readonly string _template;

    public CustomVersionedRoute(string route, int version)
    {
        _template = string.Format("v{0}/{1}", version, route);
    }

    public string Name { get { return _template; } }
    public string Template { get { return _template ; } }
    public int Order { get; set; }
}

[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class CustomersV2Controller : ApiController
{
    /* Other stuff removed */

    [VersionedRoute("Customers", 2)]
    [CustomVersionedRoute("Customers", 2)]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Json(_customers);
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct, this results in a lot of duplicate code :(. I'd much rather just set one `VersionedRoute` and one `RoutePrefix` at the top of the class and then not have to worry about the rest of the routes underneath. I've got a work around using constants to hold the routeprefix stuff, but as you can imagine its not nearly as clean as it should (could) be.

Comment: My question is how do I get that one `VersionedRoute` and one `RoutePrefix` for each so I don't have to worry about putting the versioned info above each method. I know that I can specify it manually above each but I'd like to keep it clean and DRY.

Comment: That I'm not sure of. In case it helps, one improvement would be to tidy up the `Route` attribute by making your own (see edit), which you could just pass your constants and a version to, but you'd still need two attributes on each method, one for each route.

Comment: yeah I've tried the custom attribute as well, I wish I could have multiple base classes so I could just inherit from both versionedroute and the regular attribute route and pass both versions into the template. I ended up inheriting from `RouteFactoryAttribute` when I was trying, but again its twice the magic strings :(. Thanks for trying to help me figure this out, let me know if you have any more ideas :)

Comment: You could have these "multiple base classes" by using their interfaces instead but I'm not sure this will help you. I also had this idea and created an attribute with two interfaces - `CustomVersionedRouteAttribute : Attribute, IDirectRouteFactory, IHttpRouteInfoProvider`. The problem I had was the MVC framework only seemed to recognise one route per attribute. Without changing any code inside the attribute, if I commented-out either interface it would work fine for the other case, however when both interfaces were on there it only supported one route. I can post the code I tried if it helps.

Comment: I've found the same issues :(, looks like its not possible for now, and with vNext coming soon its all going to change again anyway. For now I think I'll just stick with url versioning for everything and skip headers. Thank you for all the help trying to find a good way to do it, I'll give you the bounty but leave it unanswered for now in case someone can figure it out :)

Comment: I too would love to see a better solution, I've been fighting with this all day.