# web api 2 - how to make api versioning more elegant

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

What i want is something like the following code:

```
[VersionedRoute("api/user"), 1]
public class UserV1Controller : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("aa")]
    public int GetVal()
    {
        return 111;
    }
}

[VersionedRoute("api/user"), 2]
public class UserV2Controller : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("aa")]
    public int GetVal()
    {
        return 222;
    }
}
```

The key is I want the above code works just like **Routeprefix** with **Route**, they are so handy. I konw I can remove the "Route" attribute in the above code if there is only one method of each http verb, but it's not a good idea because I think in many cases we will use more methods in one controller. Now I have to write a lot of duplicated code using versionedRoute everywhere with a version number:

```
public class UserV1Controller : BasePublicController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [VersionedRoute("api/user/aa", 1)]
    public int GetVal()
    {
        return 111;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [VersionedRoute("api/user/bb", 1)]
    public int GetInfo()
    {
        return 123;
    }
}
```

Is there any better implementation to version web api using custom header?
Or how to upgrade the above code?
[There is a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26307695/web-api-2-api-not-recognizing-multiple-attributes-for-routing-versioning) but I didn't find a better solution to my question.

Comment: What would the URLs for the different version look like. How would one differentiate between the versioned API? via header or within the URL?

Comment: @Nkosi For example, api/user/aa with a custom header named "api-version: 1" or "api-version: 2"